# How to publish B2B Android apps to external Enterprise

Tags: android, google-play, app-distribution, line-of-business-app

Apple has the [`B2B App Store`](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) which allows a developer to "distribute tailored solutions directly to business customers". With this the app does not have to be visible to the general public.

Does Google Play have a similar setup that allows me to do the same thing? The Managed Google Play documentation has details for distribution (consumer end), but nothing detailing whether the publisher can restrict the app to particular business customers (as Windows Business Store and iOS B2B Store).

Comment: App publishing and distribution are part of Software Development, which makes this question valid here. Why the quick downvote?

Comment: I am not a registered Android developer yet. I am only doing some research at this point. So I may not be able to post on their forums.

Comment: And didn't I tell you that you would find the answer on the Google support channel; i.e. >>their<< Q&A site

Comment: @StephenC you are right. Cant take that away from you. But I'm sure I would have searched the site for weeks if I had not come to stack overflow first.

Comment: Oh really?  So you come here because there are people who have superior search skills to yours?  Like a "mechturk" for Googling?  :-)    (Hint: Google for "android private apps".  The linked page is the 2nd search result for me.)

Comment: @StephenC Im sure you have asked some questions here too, oh wise man Stephen. I come here to help and be helped. Not to accumulate 'rep' which does not mean anything to my actual day to day life. So your rep means nothing to me. You did not have the answer to my question, so as far as this question is concerned, you have been as useful as a pebble. $25 worth of my time wasted arguing with you. Thank you though :)

Comment: @StephenC Whether you wish to get this question deleted or not, thats fine. Its a valid question, and I have my answer  (which is what I came here for hehe). My day couldn't go any better...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using Google play private Chanel I am also doing the same thing for one of my customer below is link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en

Comment: It says "for internal users". My customers are external users

Comment: Actually, you are right. There is a section there that states: "To publish a private app within a client's enterprise" hidden under: "Allow a 3rd party developer to publish private apps to your domain". Totally missed it the first time. You are a here Arun

Comment: yes pnizzle i am here , I used the private Chanel for one of my customer.